# Problema con un ejecutable en Java

Tags: java, sql-server

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación de Java que se conecte con SQL Server y cuándo ejecuto en NetBeans funciona correctamente y cuando creo el .jar no funciona.

esta es mi clase de conexión a la base de datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y este es el script con el que estoy trabajando, pruebo el scrip desde el

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola. El código se comparte como texto, no como imagen. No te van a responder con imagenes para ponerte a transcribir. Puedes [edit] tu pregunta, por favor. Lo otro: por favor incluye en la pregunta cualquier mensaje de error que veas al correr el JAR. "No funciona" es una descripción bastante vaga.

Comment: [Te podrían votadr negativamente porque solo dices que no funciona.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2871/15855)